# jquery autocomplete dropdown is transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete

I am trying to use jquery autocomplete on one of my textfields, and everything seems to be ok except for the fact that the dropdown is transparent for some reason.

I am linking both jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css, both are version 1.11.4. It seems to be loading the values ok, the transparency of the dropdown seems to be the only problem. My js code is as simple as it can get:

```
$( "#edit_account" ).autocomplete({
source: dataArray
});
```

here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

I have looked around and have not found the same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: But its working completely fine here. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/gqpzot7s)

Comment: Please provide all the code necessary to reproduce the issue in your question (HTML, CSS and JavaScript).

Comment: hey, it could be an issue with z-index of the dropdown list. Try changing the background and z-index for the dropdown. You might get an idea about it. And yes, as @HiddenHobbes said, the code wud be really helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with the above case was just the transparent background.

The list that is appended to the DOM is

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-custom"></ul>
```

with the CSS

```
.ui-autocomplete-custom {
    background: #87ceeb;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This would add a color to the list, and z-index would ensure the element lies above another element.

Comment: Sorry - can you add the code example of where you set this background value. Is this css or a jquery fix?

Comment: @emeraldjava: its a pure css fix. I'll add the code in the answer asap.

Comment: @Shivi Could you please edit the answer and add the actual solution please. I came across the same issue and couldn't fix it by changing background.

Comment: @PhilipJohn updated the reply with code. Please add a fiddle in case this doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

`.ui-autocomplete {
    background-color: inherit;
}`

It works for me.

Comment: This worked for me in jQuery 3 with jQuery UI 1.12.x

Answer (score 3):

I found this as I had an issue but it was specifically on an IOS mobile device

Whilst none of the above worked the following (a hybrid of the above did)

I think this will be useful should the above not work.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using animate.css while dynamically adding Input Fields and initializing Twitter Typeahead on the same. Also tried Jquery Autocomplete but no luck, the dropdowns showed weird behaviour and were always transparent. Removing the Animate.css class did the trick for me.